# perl to python transition

Tags: python, regex, perl

I am trying to parse the flie while has a following format:

```
file.txt
10.202.34.35 username password
10.202.34.36 username password
```

In perl, I can do it using a regex such as

```
m/^(\d{1-3}.\d{1-3}.\d{1-3}.\d{1-3})\s(\w+)\s(\w+)/ then $ip = $1; $username = $2; $password = $3
```

How can I replicate this in python? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just going out on a limb here and saying you don't need a RE. Just split on a space and you will get the three parts you need.

Comment: I don't think that regexp is doing what you think it is doing. `\d[1-3].` matches a digit from 0 to 9, a digit from 1 to 3, and any character. `\d{1-3}\.` matches one to three digits from 0 to 9, and a dot.

Comment: @Amadan: `\d{1-3}` isn't valid in regex, it should be `\d{1,3}`

Comment: @M42: D'oh! Of course it should... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is with a corrected regex (free of the bugs mentioned by Amadan in the comments):

```
import fileinput
import re

pattern = '(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(\w+)\s(\w+)'

for line in fileinput.input():
    matches = re.match(pattern, line)
    if matches:
        ip, username, password = matches.groups()
        print ip, username, password
```

Comment: in pattern you dont need `^` as match, matches from the beginning of line :)

Answer (score 3):

why you need to use regex here??

try `split`:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for x in f:
        ip, username, password = x.strip().split()
        # do your stuff with variables now
```